# Heroku app - can't login with device and mongoid, monghq

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, device, mongohq, mongoid3

I have [a simple device, mongoid, mongoHQ, rails based app deployed to heroku](http://bookfoo.heroku.com). The user login gives an error.

gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'mongoid-rspec'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'email_spec'
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'launchy'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "mongoid", :git => "git://github.com/mongoid/mongoid.git"
gem "bson_ext"
gem "devise"
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
```

heroku logs are:

```
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:425:in `_run__3948797537112734549__validation__2233080772974814440__callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/callbacks.rb:100:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:53:in `run_validations!'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:179:in `valid?'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:187:in `invalid?'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/validations.rb:78:in `valid?'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/persistence/insertion.rb:22:in `prepare'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/persistence/operations/insert.rb:26:in `persist'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:50:in `insert'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/persistence.rb:79:in `save'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 heroku[router]: POST bookfoo.herokuapp.com/users dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=140ms status=500 bytes=643
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb:15:in `create'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__3306383019416481801__process_action__1212020691520070708__callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:40:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/mongoid-3936bea43ffe/lib/mongoid/unit_of_work.rb:39:in `unit_of_work'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/warden-1.2.1/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1603389820304095047__call__2233080772974814440__callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:143:in `pass'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:155:in `invalidate'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:71:in `call!'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.4.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-08-13T09:39:06+00:00 app[web.1]:
```